# ¿Como insertar una vista hija dentro de un div del layout padre? Vaadin 10 / Flow

Tags: java, vaadin

Tengo un componente que implementa **RouterLayout** de esta manera:

```
@Tag("side-menu")
@HtmlImport(value = "src/components/side-menu.html")
public class SideMenu extends PolymerTemplate<TemplateModel> implements RouterLayout {

    @Id("menu")
    private PaperListBox listBox = new PaperListBox();

    public SideMenu() {

        listBox.addMenu(new PaperItem("tutorial", TutorialView.class));
        listBox.addMenu(new PaperItem("icons", IconsView.class));

    }
}
```

Dirijo una vista secundaria del diseño principal:

```
@Route(value=IconsView.VIEW_ROUTE, layout = SideMenu.class)
public class IconsView extends Div {

    public static final String VIEW_ROUTE = "icons";

    public IconsView() {
        add(new Label("ICONS VIEW"));
    }

}
```

Pero el resultado sobreescribe todo el contenido del archivo **side-menu.html**

Formato base del modelo **side-menu.html**

```
<side-menu>
    <div>App Name</div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id=contenido><!-- Es aqui donde quiero mostrar mi vista view Icons --></div>
</side-menu>
```

Pero el resultado es esto:

```
<side-menu>
    <div>
       <label>ICONOS VIEW</label>
    </div>
</side-menu>
```

El resultado esperado, debe ser algo así:

```
<side-menu>
    <div>App Name</div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id=contenido>
       <div>
          <label>ICONOS VIEW</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</side-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentación de vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-components-in-slot.html) dice esto:

> You can add child components to templates using the `Component` or
>   `Element` API, but because PolymerTemplate uses the shadow DOM **the
>   shadow tree is rendered instead of the elements children** that are in
>   the light DOM.
>
> This means that the template needs to have a `<slot></slot>` to mark
>   the place where the light DOM elements should be rendered.

**Que resumiendo un poco al español sería algo como:**

> Puedes agregar componentes hijos a los modelos utilizando el API de
>   Componentes o Elementos. Pero como la interface PolymerTemplate usa el
>   shadowDOM (el árbol shadowDOM se dibuja en vez de los elementos hijos)
>   el cual esta en el lightDOM
>
> Esto quiere decir que se necesita agregar el tag  para
>   marcar/indicar el lugar donde el lightDOM debe dibujar los elementos

Encontré una solución para este diseño compuesto:

Solo necesitaba modificar el modelo **side-menu.html** y agregar el tag `<slot>` de esta manera:

```
<side-menu>
    <div>App Name</div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <slot></slot>
</side-menu>
```

Y luego la vista cuando se carga, es dibujada dentro del tag `<slot>` definido en el modelo.